# What is the biggest prism volume which I can draw into 2 surface?

Tags: geometry

$z = 2x^2+y^2$ and $z = 5$

I know I have to use derivatives to find the maximum value, but I am stuck. I think the biggest prism is a cylinder, so it's $V = r^2\pi m$. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: What kind of base does the prism have? Rectangle, triangle, circle, etc.? Are you allowed to choose the shape. I see you have chosen a circle.

Comment: Allowed to choose the base. I thought circle is the best, but im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A circular cylinder of radius $r$ does not intersect the bottom surface in a circle. For example, if $x=r,\,y=0$ then $z=2r^2$. If $x=0,\, y=r$ then $z=r^2$

I suspect that the base should be an ellipse with equation such as $2x^2+y^2=r^2$. Then you can find the height $z$ of the cylinder over that ellipse by checking the value of $z$ at the four "corners" of the ellipse $\left(0,\pm r\right)$ and $\left(\pm\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)$.

You will have to decide (draw a picture) whether the height is $h=z$ or $h=5-z$. One you have the height of the elliptical cylinder as a function of $r$, you can multiply it by the area of the ellipse as a function of $r$ to obtain an equation of the volume $V$ as a function of $r$.

Now you can apply the derivative to $V(r)$ to decide which value of $r$ gives a maximum value for $V$.

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to calculate with rectangle?

Comment: In that case you should probably choose a rectangle with center $(0,0,5)$ with sides aligned with the axes. The height in that case will be the height at the four corners and will be a function of two variables, length $L$ and width $W$, as will be the volume $V$. You will have to set the partial derivates of $V$ to zero taken with respect to those two variables. You could compare the maximum value with a rectangular base to the maximum value with an elliptical base.